# How to properly assign payload to GET function using express.js

Tags: node.js, express, cheerio

I am trying currently learning to build crawler using node + express +cheerio.
In the route I put this:

```
[index.js]    
app.get('/api/crawler/android', crawlerController.android);
```

which calls into controller

```
[crawler-controller.js]
var androidCrawler = require('../crawlers/android')
module.exports.android = androidCrawler.androidget;
```

then I invoke the crawler (based on cheerio)

```
[crawler.js]
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var androidget =request('https://www.developer-tech.com/categories/Android/', function (error, response, html){
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var $ = cheerio.load(html);
                var result = {result:[]};
                $('article').each(function (i, element) {
                    var Title = $(this).find("h2").text();
                    var Link = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
                    var Image = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
                    var payload = {
                        "Title":Title,
                        "Link":Link,
                        "Image":Image
                    };
                    result['result'].push(payload);            
                });
            console.log("aaa", result);
            console.log(typeof result);
            return result;
        }});
module.exports = {
    getAndroid: function (androidget, res) {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
}
```

When I console log directly to crawler.js via terminal it return JSON object properly, but I think the way I export the function to be invoked by app.get is where I'm wrong and I can't figure it out.

Perhaps somebody could help me to properly invoke the crawler in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point of returning a result in a callback function, this will just do nothing.

What you can do is wrap your request in a function and call a callback that you create : 
    // file.js
    const wrapFunction = (url, callback) => {
      request(url, ((error, response, html) => {
        // ...
        callback(result);
      })
    }

and then use it :

```
// just an example
wrapFunction(yourUrl, (result) => {
  // deal with your result
})
```

When you have that, you can export it and then use it in your middleware / controller :

```
// file.js
module.exports = wrapFunction;
```

```
// index.js
const wrapFunction = require('file.js'); // here is your function
app.get('/yourRoute', (req, res) => {
  wrapFunction(yourUrl, (result) => {
    res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
  });
})
```

**You can also use Promises :**

```
const wrapFunction = (url) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(url, ((error, response, html) => {
      if (error) reject(error);
      resolve(result);
    }); 
  });
};
```

And then :

```
wrapFunction(yourUrl).then(result => {
  // deal with your result ...
}).catch(error => {
  // deal with your error ...  
});
```

Hope it helps,
Best regards

Comment: Thank you, yes this is what I need!